# Exterior derivative commutes with postcomposition by symmetric multilinear functionals?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Let $\frak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional real Lie algebra, $\varphi: \bigotimes^l \frak{g} \to \mathbb{R}$ a symmetric multilinear functional, and $\psi \in \Omega^k(M; \bigotimes^l \frak{g})$ a $\bigotimes^l \frak{g}$-valued form on a smooth manifold $M$. Then the composite $\varphi \circ \psi \in \Omega^k(M)$ is a $k$-form on $M$ (this is true even if $\varphi$ is not symmetric).

In the famous Chern-Simons 1974 paper on [Characteristic Forms and Geometric Invariants](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1971013?seq=3#page_scan_tab_contents), it is stated (without proof) that in this situation $d(\varphi \circ \psi) = \varphi\circ d\psi$ where $d$ is the exterior derivative. Is there a coordinate-free proof for this fact? Also, is the symmetry of the multilinear map $\varphi$ a necessary requirement, or would this still be true even if $\varphi$ is merely multilinear?

Note that the Lie algebra structure of $\frak{g}$ is most likely unimportant for this statement.

Comment: Is there anywhere where the Lie algebra structure is even used here?

Comment: I doubt it. Should be true for any finite dimensional vector space. I just stated it in a similar way to the Chern-Simons paper.

Comment: It looks like chain rule. Since $\phi$ is just linear map, we get that $d\phi=\phi.$ But I am not sure how to state it rigously.

Comment: I thought the same thing; likely the symmetry of the map $\varphi$ is unimportant and the conclusion is true just because it is linear.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Just some thoughts. 

Consider the answer you edited here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21024/what-is-the-exterior-derivative-intuitively . It looks like $d$ can be somehow related to normal differential $D.$ Michael Murray pointed out, if we consider just $D,$ we wont end up with $p+1$ form. But maybe $d=\Pi\circ D$ for some projection $\Pi.$ Then maybe chain rule will hold in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question in [Dupont's Fibre Bundles and Chern-Weil Theory [PDF]](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwj92PLD3_fIAhXKp5QKHVUrAQQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.math.au.dk%2Fpublications%2Fln%2F2003%2Fimf-ln-2003-69.pdf&usg=AFQjCNESltxgqw0lHttlba-u_Rmo3oUh2A&sig2=eZftAjh1nYsEUFNj5xEzwQ). Given a vector space valued form $\omega: \bigwedge^k TM \to V$, the exterior derivative commutes with post-composition by any linear map $\varphi: V \to W$. That is, $d(\varphi \circ \omega) = \varphi \circ d \omega$. So the symmetry of the map to my question was not relevant; it was only necessary so that the resulting form would be closed.